# How do I save the csv data into the mongodb?

Tags: spring, mongodb, rest, jackson

I want to write a service method for saving bulk amount of csv data into the Mongo database keeping things in mind that it will not give some memory overflow error. 
How can I do this if anyone already done or know please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GridFS to save document larger than 16 MB, here is the link: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/gridfs/, come back again when you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to model a document based on your CSV that you're trying to store. It's hard to comment directly on your CSV format take the following for example:

```
Id,Name,Student 1 Id,Student 1 Name,Student 2 Id,Student 2 Name,Student 3 Id,Student 3 Name
48,Bill,1001,Kev,1002,Sakis,1005,Lee
78,Fred,1005,Lee,1073,Karen,1021,Jay
```

We could break this down in to a `teacher` collection:

```
{
   _id: 48,
   name: "Bill",
   students: [
     {_id: 1001, name: "Kev"},
     {_id: 1002, name: "Sakis"},
     {_id: 1005, name: "Lee"}
   ]
}

{
   _id: 78,
   name: "Fred",
   students: [
     {_id: 1005, name: "Lee"},
     {_id: 1073, name: "Karen"},
     {_id: 1021, name: "Jay"},
   ]
}
```